# Increment the numbers of all the terms in a string that follow a pattern

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk

I have something like a printf string, e.g. `The %1 fox jumped over the %2 bridge`.
And I want to transform it into `The {0} fox jumped over the {1} bridge`.
That is: get string, search for `%(\d+)` pattern, turn it into `{$1 - 1}`, repeat until the end of the string.

Is there an easy way to do that in linux (an awk one-liner for example)? I have read that sed shouldn't be an option here.

IMPORTANT: ah, unfortunately, I can't use perl solutions!

NOTES: although I think I won't find tricky stuff in my strings like `%%` or `%%1`, I was trying to implement a solution dealing with that. A test string I was using is `%1 aaa %%2 bbb%%% ccc%3.,45--- ddd%6%7`. For this test string, I would expect the output `{0} aaa %{1} bbb%%% ccc{2}.,45--- ddd{5}{6}`

Comment: do you need it to handle more than 10 replacements (that is `%1`-`%9`? or does it go to `%10`, `%11`, etc or `%A`, `%B`, etc?)

Comment: Same as in my NOTES comment. I don't think I will have to deal with that, but I'd like my solution to work on `%(\d+)` patterns, that is, with numbers of any size.

Comment: ah - then a pure regex replacement will be untenable - there will need to be increments or probably better a function to transform for each replacement

Comment: You should have mentioned the fact of having multiple `%` from the beginning, since this is an important piece of information.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that @fedorqui!

Comment: to be clear and help those trying to provide an answer, what would you want to be the result for `%1 aaa %%2 bbb%%% ccc%3.,45--- ddd%6%7` -- it's a good example, but you don't say exactly what is expected to result??

Comment: Updated. I had written it in another answer. Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another awk way

```
awk '{while(sub(/%[0-9]+/,"{"x++"}"));}!(x=0)' file
```

Just loops through the line incrementing `x` every match of `%[number]` and subbing. Sets x back to 0 at the end of line

---

For the new test string you can use

```
awk '{while(match($0,/%([0-9]+)/,a))sub(a[0],"{"a[1]-1"}")}1' file
```

Although this requires GNU awk for the third argument to match.

Example

```
%1 aaa %%2 bbb%%% ccc%3.,45--- ddd%6%7
```

becomes

```
{0} aaa %{1} bbb%%% ccc{2}.,45--- ddd{5}{6}
```

Comment: Pretty close! That is returning `{0} aaa %{1} bbb%%% ccc{2}.,45--- ddd{3}{4}` for my test string. Instead of `{0} aaa %{1} bbb%%% ccc{2}.,45--- ddd{5}{6}`

Comment: Anyway, brilliant! That's the solution I wanted in a beginning, before making up that hell of a test string :D

Comment: @rturrado Updated for new requirement.

Answer (score 2):

tAssuming no other `%` appear and they are sequential:

```
awk -F"%" -v OFS="{" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sub(i-1,i-2"}",$i)}1' file
```

This plays with the field separator setting it to `%`. This way, the field are split like this:

```
The %1 fox jumped over the %2 bridge
^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^
 $1             $2             $3
```

and then it is a matter of replacing the number `i` with `i-1` whenever reading the field `i+1`. Finally, we glue it together by setting the output field separator to `{`.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
The %1 fox jumped over the %2 bridge
The %1 fox jumped over the %2 bridge and %3 other %4 things
$ awk -F"%" -v OFS="{" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sub(i-1,i-2"}",$i)}1' a
The {0} fox jumped over the {1} bridge
The {0} fox jumped over the {1} bridge and {2} other {3} things
```

---

Note I am using [`sub()`](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html) because it replaces just once. This way, we make sure other occurrences of `1` won't be changed when modifying the field `$1`, etc.

From the link above:

> sub(regexp, replacement, target)
>
> The sub function alters the value of target. It searches this value,
>   which should be a string, for the leftmost substring matched by the
>   regular expression, regexp, extending this match as far as possible.
>   Then the entire string is changed by replacing the matched text with
>   replacement. The modified string becomes the new value of target.

Comment: I don't fully grok awk syntax, so I'm having trouble finding where it identifies/parses and assigns `i`? -- for instance, will it handle `$10`->`{9}` or `$25`->`{24}`?

Comment: @CodeJockey `$i` is the field number `i`. So `$1` is the first field, etc (and `$0` the full record). These fields are assigned based on the field separator (`-F`), so if you for example say `echo "a b c;d e f" | awk '{print NF}'` will print 6 as per six fields based on the space, but if you say `echo "a b c;d e f" | awk -F";" '{print NF}'` it will say 2 because it just has 2 `;`-separated fields.

Comment: OH - ok - I think I'm following now - but what is `NF`?

Comment: and in a format string, the `{0}` placeholders can be in any order, and can be repeated - wouldn't it break your solution, if the text was something like `The %2 fox jumped over the %1 bridge. That %2 fox is very agile!`

Comment: @CodeJockey `NF` stands for "number of fields". Regarding the repetition, I don't think this happens: it seems to be a [Python string with format placeholders](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples).

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `sed`

```
sed -r '
    # replace all leading 0s by _
    :d; s/%([0-9]+)0(\b|_)/%\1_\2/g; td; 
    # decrement last digit only
    s/%([0-9]*)1(\b|_)/%\10\2/g; 
    s/%([0-9]*)2(\b|_)/%\11\2/g; 
    s/%([0-9]*)3(\b|_)/%\12\2/g; 
    s/%([0-9]*)4(\b|_)/%\13\2/g; 
    s/%([0-9]*)5(\b|_)/%\14\2/g; 
    s/%([0-9]*)6(\b|_)/%\15\2/g; 
    s/%([0-9]*)7(\b|_)/%\16\2/g; 
    s/%([0-9]*)8(\b|_)/%\17\2/g; 
    s/%([0-9]*)9(\b|_)/%\18\2/g; 
    #remove zero to left
    s/%0(_+)/%\1/g; 
    #replace _ by 9s
    :a; s/%([0-9]+)_(\b|_)/%\19\2/g; ta;
    s/%([0-9]+)/{\1}/g;'
```

you get

```
he {0} fox jumped over the {1} bridge.
```

and

```
{0} aaa %{1} bbb%%% ccc{2}.,45--- ddd{5}{6}
```

Comment: Smart! Obviously this depends on OP's data not containing any `_` next to the number though

Comment: yes, in this case OP must use another temporary symbol, different to `_`

Comment: Could you not just check for a trailing 0(s) and change it/them to 9's in  a singe step, I can't see a reason for the temp value?

Comment: in case for example `101000`, trasform to `101___`, next to `100___`, and finally to `100999` .... the reason is when the number there are several zeros to the right

Comment: I understand what you are doing, just not why you have the intermediate step of converting to `_`. For example after your other `s//` you could have a test loop that convert trailing `0`s into 9's.

Comment: ahhh ... yes .... `:a; s/%([0-9]+)_(\b|_)/%\19\2/g; ta; ` instead of `y/_/9/;` for example ... It is better